# Differentiating pixel size in an axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I hqve an image that is is 1000x1350 in pixels. This relates to a real depth and distance (8844m x 10000m).  i have already drawn a 500x500 m grid within the image, while the grid represents a 500x500 m grid specially (derived from simple ratios) the x and y axis reflects pixels.

I have been at this all day and already wrote a bad question here on stack overflow, but I believe that I have found the right question:

Is there a way to give individual pixels a value that would represent my true distances, while keeping the same actual pixel dimensions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `extent=` parameter from `imshow()` to define the data-coordinates of your image.

[From the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

> extent : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
>
> The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right
>   corners. If None, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers
>   fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.

```
plt.imshow(img, extent=(0,8844,0,10000))
plt.xlabel('depth (m)')
plt.ylabel('distance (m)')
```

[image]

The grid depends on the ticks spacing of the axes. If you want a 500x500m grid, you have to adjust the spacing of the axes, and then enable the grid.

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,8844,500));
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10000,500));
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

Comment: This gets me on the correct track! Thank  you for your answer, you didn't go this far but from what i can gather from the documentation, the gridlines should also be able to be set using plt.?.  This really helped out.  If you have the time to share how you did the gridlines on this image that would also help, but you have answered my question, thank you again for you time!

Comment: I've added some info about the grid